# What are the benefits of Jitterbit over Lightning Connector?

Tags: lightning, jitterbit

Jitterbit appears to be priced cheaper than Lightning Connector. Besides from that, are there any other benefits to using Jitterbit instead of Lightning Connector, in the context that you wish to connect only 1 external data source to Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this video to see how Jitterbit enables to display data from external data sources (such as Databases) within Salesforce.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HpYtQKrsabA

I hope this helps.